# How can I access a common array among all PHP files in my application?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I cannot access a common array from all PHP files.

I have a PHP application set up similar to this:

```
index.php
image.php
myvars.php
functions.php
JavaScript.js
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    require("./myvars.php");
    require("./functions.php");

    session_name("myawesomesession");
    session_start();

    readfiles($myarray);

    // $MYARRAY IS POPULATED

    <img src="./image.php" />

    // $MYARRAY IS POPULATED

?>
```

**image.php**

```
<?php
    require("./myvars.php");
    require("./functions.php");

    session_name("myawesomesession");
    // have also tried "session_start();" here too.

    // $MYARRAY IS NULL

    $image = getrandomfile($myarray);
    header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($image));
    readfile($image);
?>
```

**myvars.php**

```
<?php
    $myarray = array();
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    // have also tried "session_name()" and "session_start()" here

    require("./myvars.php");

    readfiles(&$myarray){
        while(){
            array_push($myarray, $file);
        }

        // $MYARRAY IS POPULATED
    }

    getrandomfile(&$myarray){

        // $MYARRAY IS NULL

        return $random_file_from_myarray;
    }
?>
```

**JavaScript.js**

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = setimage;
xmlHttp.open("GET","./image.php",true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: Did you try storing $myarray variable in a session?

Comment: Huh ... I did not. Trying that now; I'll check back in afterwards.

Comment: @user580950 Tried it, PHP didn't like it. Kept saying "PHP Warning:  readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in ". Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing myvars.php to something like this

```
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['myarray'])) {
        $_SESSION['myarray'] = array();
    }
    $myarray = $_SESSION['myarray'];
```

and then include

```
require("./myvars.php");
```

You will get access to $myarray variable.

Comment: Tried it, PHP didn't like it. Kept saying "PHP Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given" when trying to read the directory handle obtained from using `opendir` with the `$_SESSION['myarray'];` variable.

Comment: There are a couple of things you can try to fix this issue. First, try to see if the directory path you're passing to opendir() is correct. If it is, then try to see if the permissions on the directory allow PHP to read it. If both of these are correct, then try checking if the session variables are being lost or destroyed in some way, causing the directory handle to become invalid.

Comment: You can try debugging the issue by adding some error logging and checking the log files. You can also try setting error_reporting to E_ALL and displaying errors with ini_set('display_errors', 1) to get more information about the error.

Comment: I know it cannot be permission thing as the `readfiles()` function is working well.